# failed to authenticate

Tags: login

i deleted my password after i had set it as a black field, i couldn't authenticate when installing software. i went on line asking how to get it back i got a way of doing this by booting using a live CD and deleted the code from the shadow file but now when i reboot my computer the administrator user says failed to authenticate. any with a help please. am running 11.01 on an HP- (Compaq nc6120)

Answer (score 1):

are you able to access a TTY?

if yes which would be control + alt+ F1 through F6

upon reaching a TTY follow this

- sudo passwd root
- (enter new password)
- if that doesn't work try sudo passwd yourusername
- (enter new password)
- if none of these work, only option I know would be a reinstall.

best of luck -Larry